# jquery , selector, contains one of the text

Tags: jquery, string

I need a help for one thing :

this is my jQuery  idea:

```
        var text = "Some Text1, Some Text2, Some Text3";


        $("h3:contains('"+even one of  this string+"')").each(function() {
                $(this).append("<span>Some Text</span>");
        });
```

This is My HTML

```
            <h3 class="test1">Some Text2</h3>

            <h3 class="test1">Some Text1</h3>

            <h3 class="test3">Another Text</h3>
```

What I want in OUTPUT:

```
             <h3 class="test1">
                 Some Text2
                <span>Some Text</span>
            </h3>

            <h3 class="test1">
                Some Text1
                <span>Some Text</span>
            </h3>

            <h3 class="test3">Another Text</h3>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Number of text can be different , of strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quick jQuery

```
var text = "Some Text1, Some Text2, Some Text3";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(text.split(", ")).each(function(i,v){
    $('h3:contains("'+ v +'")').append('<span>Some text</span>');
  })
})
```

quick [demo](http://jsbin.com/uhoja)

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = "Some Text1, Some Text2, Some Text3";

var aText = text.split(","); //splits into array on comma delimiter


for (var i = 0; i < aText.length; i++) {
    $("h3:contains('" + aText[i] + "')").each(function() {
        $(this).append("<span>Some Text</span>");
    });

}
```

This ought to work for you (but unclear if you can break in/out of the selector string like that. Let me know if it's good.

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate through the headings and do a regexp match on $(this).text(). You can even make this into a custom selector if you really want:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  matches: function(node, index, args, stack) {
    var re = new RegExp(args[3]);
    return !!$(node).text().match(re);
  }
});

$(function() {
  $('h3:matches("Some Text[123]")').each(function() {
    $(this).append("<span>Some Text</span>");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
$("h3:contains('Some Text1'), h3:contains('Some Text2'), h3:contains('Some Text3')").each(function() {
            $(this).append("<span>Some Text</span>");
    });
```

**EDIT**

In response to OP comment, note, you can do the following:

```
var text = "Some Text1, Some Text2, Some Text3";

text.replace(/\s?([^,]+?)(,)|\s([^,]+?)$/g, "h3:contains('$1$3')$2");
```

To generate your element list.

Then you do:

```
var text = "Some Text1, Some Text2, Some Text3";

text.replace(/\s?([^,]+?)(,)|\s([^,]+?)$/g, "h3:contains('$1$3')$2");

$(text).each(function() {
            $(this).append("<span>Some Text</span>");
    });
```

This will replace all of the comma separated terms by the term itself surrounded by h3:contains(' and '). These will be separated by commas in the same manner as the original string.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution if you know your strings ahead of time would be to use multiple selectors like so:

```
$("h3:contains('Some Text1'), h3:contains('Some Text2'), h3:contains('Some Text3')").each(function() {
    $(this).append("<span>Some Text</span>");
});
```